# In path of exile, I sometimes die well after a fight is over

Tags: path-of-exile

I'm level 94 in harbinger league.

Sometimes after a fight is over:

- My health is full and not reducing
- My energy shield is full and not reducing
- There are no large circles on the ground (such as after killing a bloodline pack)
- There is no lingering fire blob (those that chase you and blow up shortly after catching you)
- I do not have any enchantment that can harm me

But then some kind of explosion happens and I die.

I have 5k energy shield and 1.7k health.

This has happened perhaps 5-10 times, and it always seems to happen 1 to 10 seconds after a fight is over.

It just happened to me after the beachhead boss fight completed as I was picking up loot.

I suspect it could be some kind of mine or trap or something, but I cannot see anything on the ground that is killing me.

What is likely to be killing me?

Comment: Do you have any enchantment on some piece of armor that casts a spell that can harm you? (something with Chaos damage ?)

Comment: Interesting, I have not had this problem before, can you post a picture of when you died so I can see the environment?

Comment: I don't have any enchantment that can harm me. I'll take a screenshot next time it happens. I suspect some kind of mine or trap or something, but I have not been able to identify anything visually yet.

Comment: Is this a particular boss or area, or does this happen anywhere?

Comment: @VanBuzzKill Anywhere, even on some lower tiered maps. (I've had it happen anywhere from T5 maps to T16 maps). There seems to be zero graphical indication that a corpse (or something) is about to explode and one-shot builds with significant defenses (and full health/shields)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But then some kind of explosion happens and I die.

It could be a [Detonate Dead](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Detonate_Dead) effect, some monsters explode after being killed (particularly those raised by a [Stygian Revenant](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Stygian_Revenant)). Particularly in high-level areas these explosions can deal significant damage (I am pretty sure I got one-shotted as well a couple of times). An example can be seen in [this brief video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgRqFvtfD-Q).

Looking at the official forum, it seems that you/we are [not alone](https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/1977214/page/1).

An effective mitigation is to stay away from corpses for a few seconds after killing them.

Comment: Wow, nice find! I think your analysis is correct. Isn't it unfortunate that we must hold off on looting and basically refuse to cross over corpses? This seems to be a long-standing bug, which I can understand because it doesn't happen very often and it is hard to intentionally reproduce.

Comment: @BrianWebster I don't think it is a bug, all skeletons raised by a Stygian revenant explode on death. so I guess that it is intended behaviour.

Comment: Old but relevant: player at #1 in the hardcore ladder one-shotted by boss corpse explosion: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4cu567Mimgc